# resource azurerm_role_assignment is not state aware

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I assigned by Terraform role 'Reader' for specific user, on subscribtion level. It worked as I expected.
However, manually I assigned permission 'Owner'.
But after terraform plan didn't find any changes.

main.tf

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}
```

kubernetes.tf

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = "149b1d98-3260-46e7-8ab8-3c6b5297a775"
}
```

I did't see manual change in terraform state.
In GCP when I assigned roles manually, google provider was aware of changes and want to delete difference.
Why azure provider isn't aware of that?
How to control permission if terraform can't find manual changes?

Answer (score 2):

> I tracked the resource state of **azurerm_role_assignment** which isn't inherently aware of manual changes made outside of Terraform.

Concerning the SO [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666185/terraform-plan-notifies-of-changes-in-infrastructure-but-also-saying-no-changes) by [MartinAtkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281848/martin-atkins) your expectation only works for GCP as mentioned. whereas The Azure provider Terraform isn't inherently aware of manual changes made outside of Terraform. The state file Terraform maintains does not automatically sync with the actual state in the cloud unless you run Terraform refresh or apply a plan. The Google Provider might have some built-in mechanisms that more actively check for discrepancies between the state file and the actual cloud state during planning.

To confirm this I tried the demo configuration to justify my explanation.

**My Demo Terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = "User Principle ID"
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Now I make changes manually in the portal by adding a new user role for the same User ID.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now rerun the terraform script for this and check if it can take the changes that are made as we did in the portal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I thought that sth is wrong with my subscription. 
I created issue
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/24353